# Is there any HDD Regenerator alternative for Linux

Tags: hardware, data-recovery, disk-analysis

Is there any free [HDD Regenerator](http://www.dposoft.net/hdd.html) alternative for Linux?

If possible, one that can be boot using USB Flashdisk

I need it to repair possible magnetic errors on my old laptop (it doesn't have any floppy or cd-drive)